# FancyHdr top rule that is not full width

Tags: fancyhdr, rules

By default, `fancyhdr` includes a headrule separator line that spans the text width at the top of the page.  **Is there a (simpler) way to get the headrule (or footrule, for that matter) to span only, say, 50% of the text width?**

For instance, consider this MWE that does (roughly) what I've asked using a tabular to add a line manually with a little space around the title itself:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand\mytitle{Title of Document}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[c]{\begin{tabular}{c}\hspace{1in}\textsc{\mytitle}\hspace*{1in}\\\hline\end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Is there a more straightforward way to accomplish this?  The ideal solution would **not be dependent on the length of the title**, and would have an adjustable width in terms of percentage of the `\textwidth` dimension.

### Epilogue

I ended up using

```
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{\nointerlineskip\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi%
    {\hfil\rule{0.5\headwidth}{\headrulewidth}} \vskip-\headrulewidth}
\makeatother
```

in order to stay as close to the original definition made by `fancyhdr` as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\newcommand\mytitle{Title of Document}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[c]{\textsc{\mytitle}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{4pt}
\renewcommand\headrule{\makebox[\textwidth]{\rule{0.5\headwidth}{\headrulewidth}} \vskip-\headrulewidth}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Use the optional argument of `\rule` to shift the line up/down: `\rule[shift]{width}{length}`

Comment: In fact, the height of the `\makebox` seems to add space between the title and the rule that is undesirable...

Comment: Along with the addition of `\nointerlineskip` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186385), this does what I need.

Comment: USe the optional argument, e.g.: `\rule[1ex]{0.5\headwidth}{\headrulewidth}`

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty easy to do using `titlesec` instead of `fancyhdr`: its `titleps` module has a`\widenhead` command that allows enlarging header rules (indenpendently on each side); a negative value will shrink the rule. It doesn-t add any vertical space.
This supposes you don't want to write something on the left or right side of the header, but I don't see why you would with a short rule. 
Actually, you could still write on the sides but it would be more tricky.

Here is an example in which the header rule is exactly half textwidth wide:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}

\usepackage[nomarginpar]{geometry}
\newcommand\mytitle{Title of Document}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\headrule
\widenhead{-0.25\textwidth}{-0.25\textwidth}
\sethead{}{\scshape\mytitle}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}

\pagestyle{mine}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

You also can make ‘oldstyle’ headers, with a horizontal rule a little larger than the header, with this code. It uses the facilities of the `makebox` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier,heuristica}
\usepackage{makebox}

\usepackage[nomarginpar]{geometry}
\newcommand\mytitle{Title of Document}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{thine}{%
\sethead{}{\rlap{\raisebox{-1ex}{\makebox*{\enspace\scshape\mytitle\enspace}{\hrulefill}}}\enspace\scshape\mytitle}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{\hrulefill}
}

\pagestyle{thine}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I considered this (actually, with the `\fancyhfoffset` option, which does essentially the same thing), but it breaks down in the case of `\newcommand\mytitle{What if the Title of Document is Longer?}`.

Comment: I don't know well the details of fancyhdr, as I use titlesec for formatting section titles, so that I prefer to use a package of the same family, but it would have surprising it didn't have more or less the same functionalities… However I find titlesec/titleps easier to use on the whole.

Comment: We all find what we are used to easier to use, don't we?  Just why I started out with fancyhdr! :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what spacing you want, but something like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\newcommand\mytitle{Title of Document}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[c]{\textsc{\mytitle}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{4pt}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\renewcommand\headrule{%
\nointerlineskip
\hbox to \headwidth{\hss\rule{.25\headwidth}{\headrulewidth}\hss}%
\vspace{-\headrulewidth}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\nointerlineskip` was the key to the whole problem, for me at least.  Adding this also enables the solution by @Herbert perform as it should.

Comment: @cslstr thought it might be:-) a box is spaced according to baselineskip normally but a rule is not