# How to extend the fancyhdr header rule to take the full paper width

Tags: fancyhdr

I am learning LaTeX. I am using `fancyhdr`, in a book document class.

I want the horizontal rule to extend so that it takes the full page width.

[image: screenshot showing the header rule extended towards the page boundaries]

I have tried `\fancyheadoffset`, but the header content is not aligned anymore with the main content of the page.

[image: the entire header takes the page width, header content included]

I have also tried using a `\makebox` and renew the `\headrule` command, but it creates unwanted vertical space that I could not control (solution based on an answer on this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186350/fancyhdr-top-rule-that-is-not-full-width)).

How can I have only the hrule extending?

[image: visual explanation of the expected result]

## Files

### Document class based on book

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{novel}[2024/02/01 Novel]


\LoadClass[12pt,a5paper,twoside,openright]{book}


% UTF-8 support.
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%%%%%%%%%%%
% Layout. %
%%%%%%%%%%%

% Basic layout.
\RequirePackage[
    papersize={152mm,214mm},
    layout=a5paper,
    layouthoffset=2mm,
    layoutvoffset=2mm,
    bindingoffset=8mm,
    left=17mm,
    right=17mm,
    top=17mm,
    bottom=17mm,
    %showframe
]{geometry}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Formatting. %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Helps build better header and footer; places the page number in the footer.
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

% Redefine fancy style.
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{

    \fancyheadoffset[loh,reh]{27mm}
    \fancyheadoffset[roh,leh]{19mm}

    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[EL]{\smaller{\smaller{\textit{\MakeUppercase{\vspace{\baselineskip} \\ \thetitle}}}}}
    \fancyhead[OR]{\smaller{\smaller{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ \\ \leftmark}}}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\smaller{\thepage}}}

% Redefine plain style to match fancy style.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \addtolength{\headwidth}{0cm}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\smaller{\thepage}}}

% Removes headers on empty pages.
\RequirePackage{emptypage}

% Used for convenient title management.
\RequirePackage{titling}

% Font size adjustment commands.
\RequirePackage{relsize}

% Reduces widows and orphans.
\RequirePackage[all]{nowidow}

% Change the chapter title in the header to only the chapter title.
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Typography. %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Fixes some hyphenation issues (lines longer than body width).
\sloppy

% Micro-typographical adjustments. TODO: reevaluate usefulness
\RequirePackage{microtype}

% Remove space between paragraphs.
\RequirePackage[skip=0pt,indent=15pt]{parskip}
```

### Main TeX file

```latex
\documentclass[]{novel}


% This is necessary for proper language-specific hyphenation.
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[]{lipsum}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Metadata. %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\author{NemuLumeN}
\title{Title of the book}
\date{2022}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter title}


\lipsum[1-10]


\chapter{Second chapter}

Oh yeah
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  We need to know at least the document class, and how you are now using it.  Please provide a small compilable example beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows the result you get now.

Comment: Also, tell us whether the title is always supposed to be aligned to the outside margin, or always to the left margin.

Comment: In the question you mentioned, it said "Use the optional argument of `\rule` to shift the line up/down: `\rule[shift]{width}{length}`"

Comment: @Tom How does that help?

Comment: Use `\fancyheadoffset[<place>]{<adjustment>}`. You'll need one for the left and one for the right. If you're using double-sided, you'll need two places for each; otherwise, one will do. The adjustment will be negative for the right/inner margin and positive for the left/outer. This may not work if you are attempting to use `fancyhdr` with a non-standard class, conflicting packages or other ill-advised stuff ;).

Comment: Welcome. // Do I get it right, the text alignments in the header shall remain, only the rule shall go accross the whole page?

Comment: I have added the source of my project: the document class and the tex file.
@MS-SPO Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Tom I will try this right now; I overlooked this detail. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, following the suggestion from @Tom, I tried again using the makebox solution from the other question, applied the “shift” option, and it worked (I think).

```latex
\makeatletter
    \def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
        \makebox[\linewidth]{\rule[\linewidth]{\dimexpr(\paperwidth + 8mm)}{\headrulewidth}}
        \vskip-315.69928pt}}%
\makeatother
```

## Explanation

I renewed `\headrule` of the `fancyhdr` package, by encapsulating the original `\rule` into the `\makebox`. I'm not sure the rule fits exactly the real page width, but at least, there are no visible gaps. (I think that the rule extends beyond the paper limits.)

I had to adjust the original `\vskip` of the `fancyhdr` package because the log showed this output:

```
Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):
(fancyhdr) Make it at least 301.59924pt, for example:
(fancyhdr) \setlength{\headheight}{301.59924pt}.
(fancyhdr) You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:
(fancyhdr) \addtolength{\topmargin}{-289.59924pt}.
```

Changing the original `\vskip` to -315.69928pt “fixes” the error. I don't know why nor what exactly is fixed, though, as nothing changes visually, whether the value is set or not.

## Result

[image: capture on even page]

[image: capture on odd page]